# Why were the original authors of Django against include tags?

Tags: django, django-templates

In [this excellent Google Tech Talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aJ_7KtjIVLQ) by Jacob Kaplan-Moss, Jacob says that they added support for the `include` template tag despite previous dogmatic objections, and says that people shouldn't use it.

Does anyone know why? A quick search didn't show anything that would explain why. There's nothing relevant in the [now-fixed ticket](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/598) where support for an `include` tag was added. I use include tags liberally to avoid repeating myself, which [seems like a good idea](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/misc/design-philosophies/#don-t-repeat-yourself-dry), but maybe I'm missing some core reason why those who know think it's bad.

Comment: I'd guess that is because you should be extending templates, instead of having a bung of includes on your every template for extension.

Comment: @voyager - I'm not sure how that would work in practice - care to post an example as an answer?

Comment: Great link by the way; I might not have watched this video if it weren't for this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suppose he wants to encourage template reuse by inheritance (using `extends`) rather than by composition. Perhaps the implication is that if you can't organise your templates this way, the dogmatic opinion is that your site is organised poorly. (For example, if you are reusing a navigation menu, shouldn't it always be in the same place in the page structure? Why should each individual page decide where to put it?)

By the way, using `include` doesn't do much to help you stay DRY, because any context that the included template requires must be passed from all the views that use it.

By contrast, using a custom [inclusion template tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) allows you to execute arbitrary Python code at the point where the tag is included, rather than in the view (or by shoving it into a model just to make it easier to access in the template).

As a trivial example, I wanted to show a list of users' avatars. Using `include`, it looks like this:

```
{% for user in users %}
    {% with user.gravatar_url as avatar_url %}
        {% include "foo/bar/avatar.html" %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

With a custom tag:

```
{% for user in users %}
    {% gravatar user.email %}
{% endfor %}
```

Using the custom inclusion tag meant that the [Gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/) hashing logic no longer had to be a concern of the `User` model, nor of the view function.

---

This said, I think are are some situations where you inevitably have similar data in the context of multiple templates, you don't need to do anything fancy with it, you just want to display some of its attributes so you don't want to write a function to make it work.

For example, I wrote a blog application (who hasn't?) which had two types of archive view: a basic sequential, X-posts-per-page one, and a monthly archive view. Both templates obviously had a list of posts in their context, both used exactly the same summary template fragment to show a title and excerpt from each post, but each template presented them in a slightly different context. So I used:

```
{# in archive_index.html #}
{% extends "base.html" %}

{# some stuff specific to sequential archives here #}

{% for post in posts %}
    {% include "post_summary.html" %}
{% endfor %}

{# probably more stuff specific to sequential archives #}
```

And...

```
{# in archive_monthly.html #}
{% extends "base.html" %}

{# some stuff specific to monthly archives here #}

{% for post in posts %}
    {% include "post_summary.html" %}
{% endfor %}

{# probably more stuff specific to monthly archives #}
```

It really seems that in this case, composition makes more sense than inheritance. In fact it was difficult at first to imagine how inheritance would work here at all. Well, it's still possible:

```
{# in base_archive.html #}
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block archive_header %}{% endblock %}

{% for post in posts %}
    {% include "post_summary.html" %}
{% endfor %}

{% block archive_pagination %}{% endblock %}
```

Now, the two different archives extend this and just inject their unique stuff into the blocks:

```
{# in archive_monthly.html #}
{% extends "base_archive.html" %}

{% block archive_header %}
    <h1>Archive for {{ month }}</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block archive_pagination %}
    {# previous/next month links here #}
{% endblock %}
```

I'll leave imagining what `archive_index.html` looks like as an exercise for the (no doubt bored) reader.

Phew! It feels smart to have come up with a way of doing the same thing using both composition and inheritance, but is the latter just bending over backwards to conform to the dogma that Jacob Kaplan-Moss mentioned?

Having just watched the video (yes, all 1 hour 5 minutes of it, just so I could finish answering this question), I don't think Jacob would be enormously bothered. It sounded like an off-the-cuff comment, maybe a reference to which technique you *ought* to consider first.

Comment: @Ben - within the context of loops is always where I reach for `include` - that's a really helpful example - thanks! Could you show me an example of replacing an `include` tag with template inheritance? I'm having difficulty getting my head around how that might work.

Comment: Dominic, I have done my best to give such an example, see my edit after the line.

Comment: That is by far and away the most effort I've ever seen anyone put into an answer, and is very helpful. (Sorry for not responding until now - didn't see your edit).

Comment: It was not really that great an effort considering I'm simply repeating (albeit in simplified form) template structures that I'd already written!