# Django Custom Inclusion Tags

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to build my own template tags. 
I have no idea why I getting these errors. I'm following the Django doc's.

This is my app's file structure:

```
pollquiz/
    __init__.py
    show_pollquiz.html
    showpollquiz.py
```

This is showpollquiz.py:

```
from django import template
from pollquiz.models import PollQuiz, Choice
register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('show_pollquiz.html')
def show_poll():
    poll = Choice.objects.all()
    return { 'poll' : poll }
```

html file:

```
<ul>
{% for poll in poll 
    <li>{{ poll.pollquiz }}</li>
{% endfor 
</ul>
```

in my base.html file im am including like this

```
{% load showpollquiz %}
and
{% poll_quiz %}
```

Bu then I get the the error:

```
Exception Value: Caught an exception while rendering: show_pollquiz.html
```

I have no idea why this happens. Any ideas? Please keep in mind I'm still new at Django

Comment: Have you done the tutorial? Are you extending the tutorial? Several things look odd to me (you're keeping templates in the same directory as Python code, you've got an inclusion tag called `show_poll`, but I can't see where you're using it - you're using a custom tag called `poll_quiz`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Shouldn't all custom filters be inside the templatetags directory?

```
templatetags/
    __init__.py
    showpollquiz.py
```

then

```
@register.inclusion_tag('show_pollquiz.html')
```

looks in MY_TEMPLATE_DIR/show_pollquiz.html for the template

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to close your template tags... Also, you should change the name in the `for` tag, you can't have `for poll in poll`:

```
<ul>
{% for p in poll %} <!--here-->
    <li>{{ p.pollquiz }}</li>
{% endfor %} <!--and here-->
</ul>
```

Also notice you're not using the inclusion tag you defined at all. I think you got some code mixed up, try to go over [a tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api) start to end and things will be clearer.

Comment: Hi there.

I closed the endfor tag but the same error still come up

Comment: The docs you refer to are for Django 0.95. The latest ones are over here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/

Answer (score 0):

I'd not bother with writing your own template tags: take things one step at a time and stick to the basics for now. There's nothing wrong with `{% include 'show_pollquiz.html' %}`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357493/why-were-the-original-authors-of-django-against-include-tags

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The problem was that the @register.inclusion_tag('show_pollquiz.html')
 inclusion tag is obviously looking for the template in the default_template directory. So that is why i got the error.

According to me this is not clear in the documentation. But I guess its how it is, being a template and all...

Oh , well.

Now, how would I put the @register.inclusion_tag('show_pollquiz.html') to look in the same folder as the app? under templatetags/?