# Django - same html, different views

Tags: html, django, django-templates, django-views

I want to have a block oh html across all my templates (like a sidebar for basic form submissions), which is easily implemented on the html files by using blocks.

However, my doubt is not about the repetitions across templates, but across views. Since the functionality will be the same across all templates, it would be really boring (and bad programming) to define the request handling (that would come from that side bar's submissions) for every view I have! How should I handle this? Should (and can) I make a view dedicated to handling that "all-around" part of the template?

Any advices are welcome,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Daniel is refering to an [Inclusion Tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags)

Basically, a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#custom-template-tags-and-filters) is used for scenarios like yours (... code reusability amongs many other advantages)

Also this post might be helpful: [Django Custom Inclusion Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370110/django-custom-template-tages-inclusion-tags)

Another approach could be using [`template inheritance`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#custom-libraries-and-template-inheritance) - create a base template, which defines the layout, and override the blocks of code that would change for specific views.

Here is an example of template inheritance: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance

Comment: The thing is, my problem is not about the template reusage, but about the views. Since every template will have that piece of code, every view will have to have the code regarding that template block.

Comment: No. you dont have to include it in the view. It is just called in the template, and not in the view.

Comment: In the link, you can see how to use a custom template tag (Note that you dont have to do anything in the view)

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom template tag - probably an inclusion tag.