# How to put "python functions" into HTML files in a Django Project

Tags: django, web-development-server

Working in a Django Project. I have an index.html file with a variable called "todas_academias", which is a list of models classes that I've created. 
Directory: FKSC/ac_filiados/templates/ac_filiados/index.html

```
{% for academia in ordenar(todas_academias) %}
                 <td>{{ academia.nome_academia }}</td>
                 <td>{{ academia.estado }}</td>
                 <td>{{ academia.cidade }}</td>
                 <td>{{ academia.professor }}</td>
                 <td>{{ academia.num_alvara }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

And I created a function called "ordenar" in a python file in another directory.
Directory: FKSC/ac_filiados/functions.py

You **DON'T NEED** to understand what this function does.

```
def ordenar(todas_academias):
    lista = []
    for academia in todas_academias:
        lista = lista + [academia.num_alvara]
    nova_list = lista.sort()
    nova_lista_academias = []
    for reg in nova_list:
        for academia in todas_academias:
            if reg == academia.num_alvara:
                nova_lista_academias = nova_lista_academias + [academia]
    return nova_lista_academias
```

Now, I just want to use the "ordenar()" function in the index.html file, as I tried to use, but it didn't work. 
1) Do I need to import the "ordenar" function before using it? If so, How do I import it? 
2) Should I've placed the "ordenar" function in views.py?
3) Or, is there a specific way of using this kind of functions in HTML files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't call a function from the template. I would pass what ordenar returns via context dictionary to the view like so:

views.py

```
def ordenar(todas_academias):
    lista = []
    for academia in todas_academias:
        lista = lista + [academia.num_alvara]
    nova_list = lista.sort()
    nova_lista_academias = []
    for reg in nova_list:
        for academia in todas_academias:
            if reg == academia.num_alvara:
                nova_lista_academias = nova_lista_academias + [academia]
    return nova_lista_academias 

def some_view(request):
    ...
    YOUR OTHER CODE
    ...
    return render(request, 'yourtemplate.html', {ordenar: 'ordenar'})
```

Then in your template you would keep the same code more or less:

```
{% for academia in ordenar %}
    <td>{{ academia.nome_academia }}</td>
    <td>{{ academia.estado }}</td>
    <td>{{ academia.cidade }}</td>
    <td>{{ academia.professor }}</td>
    <td>{{ academia.num_alvara }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add result of your function inside the context of your view or create django template tag inclusion-tags [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) and example: [custom-inclusion-tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370110/django-custom-inclusion-tags)